# Perl: Combining two arrays, removing identical headers, keeping format

Tags: arrays, perl, split, mesh

Below you will see the contents of two arrays I have generated. How can I combine the two arrays, remove the repeated identical headers, but keep the same format- almost like building a matrix? I am currently using mesh to combine the arrays into one, but it doesn't quite work. I haven't come across anything else that might be able to help either, like split, push, etc. I have shown my code below.

**Input file "phred.txt"**

```
 "#$%&'()
```

**Input file "bases.txt"**

```
ABCDEFGH
```

**Output from printing array 1**

```
Sequence_1 
1     2     3     4    5
```

**Output from printing array 2**

```
Sequence_1 
A     B     C     D    E
```

**Desired output from combining both arrays**

```
Sequence_1
1     2     3     4     5
A     B     C     D     E
```

**Results from current strategy of using mesh**

```
Sequence_1
Sequence_1
1A     2B     3C     4D     5E
```

**Current Code**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::MoreUtils qw(mesh);

open( PHRED, '<', '/path/to/phred.txt' ) or die $!;
open( BASES, '<', '/path/to/bases.txt' ) or die $!;
open( OUT,   '>', '/path/to/out.txt' )   or die $!;

my @symbols;
my @bases;
my $count = 0;
my @finalphred;
my @finalbases;

my %hash = (
    '"'  => "1",
    '#'  => "2",
    '$'  => "3",
    '%'  => "4",
    '&'  => "5",
    q(') => "6",
    '('  => "7",
    ')'  => "8"
);

while ( my $fastq = <PHRED> ) {
    my $substring = substr( $fastq, 0, 5 );
    push( @symbols, $substring );
}

foreach ( @symbols ) {

    my @eachsymbol = split //, $_;
    $count++;
    push( @finalphred, "\n", "Sequence_$count\n" );

    foreach my $symbol ( @eachsymbol ) {
        if ( exists( $hash{$symbol} ) ) {
            push( @finalphred, $hash{$symbol}, "\t" );
        }
    }
}

my $count_again = 0;

while ( my $fastq_again = <BASES> ) {
    my $substring_again = substr( $fastq_again, 0, 5 );
    push( @bases, $substring_again );
}

foreach ( @bases ) {
    my @eachsymbol_again = split //, $_;
    $count_again++;
    push( @finalbases, "\n", "Sequence_$count_again\n" );
    foreach my $symbol_again (@eachsymbol_again){ 
         push (@finalbases, $symbol_again, "\t");
    }
}
foreach (@finalphred){ #diagnostic to test array contents
     print "$_"; 
} 
foreach (@finalbases){ #diagnostic to test array contents
     print "$_"; 
} 
my @last = mesh @finalphred, @finalbases;

print OUT @last;
```

Thank you for helping me finish this code and for getting the right output!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi Matt, I just edited my question to include a description of what I need help with. Basically, I am looking to print my two arrays as a single array so that it looks like my "desired output from combining both arrays"

Comment: What about some sample input? The problem is not easy to reproduce as written; see: [mcve].

Comment: Your code certainly doesn't produce the output that you say it does. The values in `@eachsymbol_again` are never output at all. If you really want us to help you then you need to tell the truth.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Borodin- not sure about what caused you to think of me as a liar, but I have tried to improve my question with your suggestions, as well as the others. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve my question.

Comment: @MattJacob, I have improved my question to include the input data. It should be reproducible now. Thanks.

Comment: Simply your words *"Results from current strategy of using mesh"*, which is clearly not true, unless you meant something other than the code you have posted, which would be rather strange.

Comment: Yes- after looking at the code I posted I had left out some lines of code- which I have now included. I didn't intend to not tell the truth, and appreciate you pointing out the deficiency in my question. Any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is important to post an exact copy of your code, or of a program that displays the same problems. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main problems is that you never print out any of the contents of `@eachsymbol_again`. You split each four-character string into four characters and put it into that array, but then ignore it. It certainly doesn't produce the output that you say it does.

Also, `mesh` is a strange choice to combine your arrays like that

For reference, your arrays look like this

#### @finalphred

```
[
  "\n",
  "Sequence_1\n",
  1,
  "\t",
  2,
  "\t",
  3,
  "\t",
  4,
  "\t",
  "\n",
  "Sequence_2\n",
  5,
  "\t",
  6,
  "\t",
  7,
  "\t",
  8,
  "\t",
)
```

#### @finalbases

```
(
  "\n",
  "Sequence_1\n",
  "\n",
  "Sequence_2\n"
)
```

You don't even have the same number of elements in those two arrays, so calling `mesh` on them doesn't make much sense

---

#### Update

Here's a working program

I used the following data

#### phred.txt

```
"#$%
&'()
```

#### bases.txt

```
ABCD
EFGH
```

#### Perl code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %xlate = map { chr($_ + 33) => $_ } 1 .. 8;

open my $phred_fh, '<', 'phred.txt';
open my $bases_fh, '<', 'bases.txt';

my $n;

until ( eof $phred_fh or eof $bases_fh ) {

    my @syms = map [ split //, substr <$_>, 0, 4 ], $phred_fh, $bases_fh;

    printf "Sequence_%d\n", ++$n;
    print join("\t", map $xlate{$_}, @{$syms[0]}), "\n";
    print join("\t", @{$syms[1]}), "\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Sequence_1
1   2   3   4
A   B   C   D

Sequence_2
5   6   7   8
E   F   G   H
```

Comment: I believe I have now addressed your criticism. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to help get to an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `mesh` at all for this work. It is more trivial to read the files into an array process them and then write them into file with formatting. Meanwhile, if file size is large to fit into main memory then it can also modified for line by line processing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open( PHRED, '<', 'phred.txt' ) or die $!;
open( BASES, '<', 'bases.txt' ) or die $!;
open( OUT,   '>', 'out.txt' )   or die $!;

my @finalphred;
my @finalbases;

my %hash = (
    '"'  => "1",
    '#'  => "2",
    '$'  => "3",
    '%'  => "4",
    '&'  => "5",
    q(') => "6",
    '('  => "7",
    ')'  => "8"
);

while ( my $fastq = <PHRED> ) {
    chomp $fastq;
    my @items = split //, $fastq;
    my @phreds = map {$hash{$_}} grep {exists $hash{$_}} @items;
    push (@finalphred, \@phreds);
}

while ( my $fastq_again = <BASES> ) {
    chomp $fastq_again;
    my @items = split //, $fastq_again;
    push(@finalbases, \@items);
}

for my $i (0 .. $#finalbases) {
    if(@{$finalbases[$i]} && @{$finalphred[$i]}) {
        print OUT "Sequence_" . ($i + 1),"\n";
        printf OUT "%-6s" x scalar @{$finalphred[$i]},@{$finalphred[$i]};
        print OUT "\n";
        printf OUT "%-6s" x scalar @{$finalbases[$i]},@{$finalbases[$i]};
        print OUT "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Both arrays doesn't contain equal no of elements\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Perl 6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

subset File of Str where *.IO.f;

sub MAIN (File :$phred='phred.txt', File :$bases='bases.txt') {
    my $phred-fh = open $phred;
    my $bases-fh = open $bases;
    my %xlate    = map { chr($_ + 33) => $_ }, 1..8;

    for 1..* Z $phred-fh.IO.lines Z $bases-fh.IO.lines -> ($i, $score, $seq) {
        put join "\n",·
            "Sequence_$i",·
            (map { %xlate{$_} }, $score.comb).join("\t"),·
            $seq.comb.join("\t");
    }
}
```